# Can't change HTML after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I can't change HTML after a javascript timeout. Here's the code I'm using:

`setTimeout("$(\"#display p\").html(newDescription);", 250);`

Is there something wrong with this? If I remove the timeout, the script works perfectly. Here's that version:

`$("#display p").html(newDescription);`

I'm running Chrome 22 if that makes any difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes the first argument should be function.

```
var newDescription = 'The Description';
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#display p").html(newDescription);
}, 250);
```

OR

```
var newDescription = 'The Description',
    myfunc = function(){
       $("#display p").html(newDescription);
    };

setTimeout(myFunc, 250);
```

Additionally `newDescription` must be in a scope accessible to your function.

Comment: However, the first argument could also be a string.

Comment: @prodigitalson: it doens't need to resolve to a function. The string arguments just gets `eval`uated by JS.

Comment: @jAndy: duely noted, but lets not seem like we are encouraging that :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson: true. You'll have my +1 if you also mention that the code doesn't work in its current form because of different context's and the JS engine might not be able to resolve `newDescription`.

Comment: @jAndy: +1, this is true, but i think its a fair assumption since he only posted that snippet that `newDescription` is in the global scope or otherwise available.

Comment: @prodigitalson: I really think its not in the global scope. Otherwise the code would work and the OP wouldn't have the need to ask :)

Comment: @jAndy Indeed. If `newDescription` were a global variable, it would be available in the global context in which eval() executes the code. The reference to the variable is lost precisely because there is no scope keeping it alive.

Answer (score 2):

When passing a string to setTimeout, the code is evaluated in the **global scope**. More than likely, `newDescription` is a *local variable* and thus unavailable when the code gets evaluated after the 250 ms timeout.

You shouldn't ever pass strings to setTimeout(), for the same reasons you shouldn't use eval(). By passing a function, you retain your scoped variables and you get better performance as the JavaScript engine can optimize your function (whereas it's not possible to optimize code in a string argument).

```
var newDescription = "My fancy new description";
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#display p").html(newDescription);
}, 250);
```

Comment: Also, passing a function argument creates a closure that stores any local variables so that they can be used even after the timeout :)

Comment: @DavidMårtensson Exactly! Even after the outer function returns, the setTimeout callback function keeps the `newDescription` variable alive so it can be accessed when the timer runs out.